# How to delete feature from shapefile using GDAL C++?

Tags: c++, gdal, shapefile

I am using GDAL version 2.0.0.

I have a C++ program in which I want to delete a feature from a shapefile.  The return error code indicates successful deletion.  However, the feature remains in the shapefile.

Is there some subsequent function I must call so that the deletion will persist?  For example, when you make a change to a field of an existing feature, you have to subsequently call `OGRLayer::SetFeature()` again, or else the change does not persist.

Following is a snippet of what I am doing.  The shapefile is created from scratch, by polygonizing a raster file.  I then attempt to delete one feature from that shapefile before closing the file.

```
#include <gdal_alg.h>     // GDALPolygonize()
#include <gdal_priv.h>

//
// srcPath is the path of the soruce raster geospatial file.  e.g., a GeoTIFF file.
// tgtPath is the path of the target vector geospatial file.  i.e., a shapefile.
//
void test( char const * srcPath, char const * tgtPath )
{
  GDALAllRegister();

  // Open source file.
  GDALDataset * pSrcDataset = static_cast<GDALDataset *>( GDALOpen( srcPath, GA_ReadOnly ) );

  GDALRasterBand * pSrcBand = pSrcDataset->GetRasterBand( 1 );

  // Create and open target file.
  GDALDriver * pDriver = GetGDALDriverManager()->GetDriverByName( "ESRI Shapefile" );
  GDALDataset * pTgtDataset = pDriver->Create( tgtPath, 0, 0, 0, GDT_Unknown, NULL );

  // Create a layer.
  OGRLayer * pTgtLayer = pTgtDataset->CreateLayer( "layer", NULL, wkbPolygon, NULL );

  // Create a field to contain value associated with each polygon feature.
  OGRFieldDefn field( "value", OFTInteger );
  field.SetWidth( 6 );
  pTgtLayer->CreateField( &field );

  // Call GDALPolygonize to convert source raster to polygon features.
  GDALRasterBand * pMaskBand = NULL;
  int valueFieldIdx = 0;
  char ** options = NULL;  
  GDALPolygonize(
    pSrcBand,
    pMaskBand,
    pTgtLayer,
    valueFieldIdx,
    options,
    GDALTermProgress, NULL );  

  // Demonstrate that the target layer has the capability to delete a feature.
  if ( !pTgtLayer->TestCapability( OLCDeleteFeature ) )
  {
    throw "Layer does not support delete feature capability";
  }

  // Delete a feature that I know is there.
  // The feature has a particular integer ID.
  OGRErr err = pTgtLayer->DeleteFeature( 12 );

  // Demonstrate that there is a zero error code, indicating successful deletion.
  if ( err != OGRERR_NONE )
  {
    throw "Failed to remove feature";
  }

  // Close source and target files.
  GDALClose( pSrcDataset );
  GDALClose( pTgtDataset );
}
```

Comment: What is `pLayer`? Is that a typo?

Comment: It was indeed a typo.  I fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I learned from a colleague something that forces the feature deletion to persist in the file.  After I have done all feature deletions, and before I close the shapefile, I do the following.

```
  // Delete features.
  ...

  // Flush pending changes.
  pTgtLayer->SyncToDisk();

  // Execute a SQL command.
  // It is essential, to force my changes to take effect.
  // As a side effect, it renumbers the features to fill in
  // the gaps left by deleted features.
  stringstream sql;
  sql << "REPACK " << pTgtLayer->GetName();
  pTgtDataset->ExecuteSQL( sql.str().c_str(), NULL, NULL );

  // Close files.
  ...
```

Comment: Alternatively, instead of calling `OGRLayer::SyncToDisk()`, it also works to call `GDALDataset::FlushCache()`, which the documentation says will call `SyncToDisk()` on all layers.  I tested this alternative, and it worked also.

Comment: If you have solved the problem then why not accept your answer too?